# Hadoop setup issue: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: No address associated with hostname"

Tags: hadoop, ssh

When I build hadoop cluster  based on vmware, and I use `sbin/start-dfs.sh` command, I meet the problem about ssh. It says,

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: No address associated with hostname

I have used `vi /etc/hosts` command to check the hostname and IP address, and `vi /etc/profile` command. I ensure that there is no fault.

Comment: Is this a single node or multi-node cluster?

Comment: this is a multi-node cluster

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions

1. Check if the hostnames in hdfs-site.xml is set correctly. If you are running with single host setup, and you set namenode host as localhost, you need to make sure localhost mapped to 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts. If you are setting multiple nodes, make sure you use FQDN of each host in your configuration, and make sure each FQDN mapped to the correct IP address in /etc/hosts.
2. Setup passwordless SSH. Note start-dfs.sh requires that you have passwordless SSH setup from the host where you run this command to rest of cluster nodes. Verify this by `ssh hostx date` and it doesn't ask for a password.
3. Check the hostname in the error message (maybe you did not paste the complete log), for the problematic hostname, run SSH command manually to make sure it can be resolved. If not, check /etc/hosts. A common /etc/hosts setup looks like

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
>
> ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain
>
> 172.16.151.224 host1.test.com host1
>
> 172.16.152.238 host2.test.com host2
>
> 172.16.153.108 host3.test.com host3